# BASH: insert text in a specific position

Tags: bash, text, grep

I would like to find a solution to add some characters in a string

Example

```
folder/dir/directory/file.txt
shares/page.html
etc/downloads/torrent.torrent
```

Should become

```
.folder.old/dir/directory/file.txt
.shares.old/page.html
.etc.old/downloads/torrent.torrent
```

How can i do that? 'grep' would be a correct choose?

Thank you

Comment: `sed` is the command you want for this problem, not `grep`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `sed` instead of `grep`:

```
sed -i.bak 's#^\([^/]*\)#.\1.old#'
```

Note that `-i` will save the result in the original file itself. `-i.bak` will save your original file with `.bak` extension in case something goes wrong.

Comment: You can use this on a group of files like: `sed -i.bak 's#^\([^/]*\)#.\1.old#' *.txt`

Answer (score 5):

`grep` only searches, it doesn't do replacement. You want `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's#^\([^/]*\)#.\1.old#'
```

`^` means beginning of the line
`\(...\)` is capturing parentheses, the pattern it matches becomes `\1` in the replacement.
`[^/]` matches anything but `/`
`*` is zero or more of the preceding